# How to render object in object in json

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json

I want to render the lat in location from the api I tried the map function but it didn't worked plea

```js
function App() {
  const [loc, setloc] = useState([])

  const getData = () => {
    fetch('https://geo.ipify.org/api/v2/country,city?apiKey=at_2ZscU5cJBQppsBivxjTzLMx7pHZYt')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
       
        setloc(res)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])
  return (
  {loc.map(item =>{
  return(
    {item.location}
  )
})
}    )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The api is not returning an array, that's why your mapping is not working. You can render the API response like in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-aryabhata-shivvg?file=/src/App.js). You can access the latitude with `loc.location.lat` directly .

Comment: Adding an `isLoading` state would also be a good idea. I added `loc && loc.location.lat` to delay rending until the object is available.